# Mongodb get counts in single row

Tags: mongodb

I have data like this:

[ { type: 'A',
code: '001',
name: 'account 001' },
{ type: 'A',
code: '001',
name: 'account 001' },
{ type: 'B',
code: '001',
name: 'account 001' },
{ type: 'C',
code: '004',
name: 'test_account' },
{ code: '002',
type: 'A',
name: 'account 002' },...

There are only 3 types, A, B and C. Code field and name field are related, ex: code:"002" means name field="account 002"

I want to get total counts, target output should contain fields like:

**name-code-totalA-totalB-totalC**

```
account 001-001-300-400-100

account 002-002-150-50-250 

test account-004-900-100-45
```

---

I cannot get total counts in one row, is there a way to get total A, B, C counts in one row in mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

`$group`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        type: "$type",
        code: "$code",
        name: "$name"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "code": "$_id.code",
        "name": "$_id.name"
      },
      "types": {
        "$push": {
          "type": "$$ROOT._id.type",
          "count": "$$ROOT.count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ilm2dVEw4VR)